# MAUI Preview 12 iOS Debugging

Tags: ios, iphone, maui, .net-maui

After upgrading to VS2022 preview 3 and Maui Preview 12 I'm no longer able to debug iOS apps.   Break point so get hit but no code is visible.

[Appliation in break mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CYp5.png)

I have tried this on a new windows 11 install and clean install of visual studio, also tried using two phones and repeated test on another pc.

Anyone having the same issue or any suggestions.

Comment: Have you reopen the VS? When you create a new app, could you debug it? If you still could not, you could try to repair the Visual Studio.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT , I have tried repairing VS, reinstalling VS, a completely new Win11 and VS install, doesn't work across multiple PC's and devices.  Just updated to latest 2022 preview and still no luck.  I can debug fine if I create a Xamarin App on but not if I create a Maui App

Answer (score 0):

You could use the latest Visual Studio. Upgrade the Visual Studio preview 3 to preview 4 maybe fix this issue. I tested on preview 4 on Win11. It could debug the app and run it well.

My tested Visual Studio version:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
  Version 17.1.0 Preview 4.0

Comment: on main pc upgraded to preview 4 not working, on laptop uninstalled preview 3 installed preview 4 still not working both systems have no problems debugging xamarin app using the preview.  I'm using the Enterprise version of VS2022 preview., Windows 11 Insider Program - Release Preview

Comment: I used Windows 11 Enterprise 21H2 with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.0.4. Have you try on another PC? When you uninstall, have you removed the caches and config files/folders?

Comment: As previously stated I have tried on two pc's both from a new windows install so was completely new system also tried with two different iphone 12's.  I just uninstalled VS including the installer, cleared nuget caches, deleted all VS folders from program files(x86), program files, program data and local storage in my profile also cleared the xamarin folders.  removed all registry settings I could find as well.  Installed 2022 community edition 17.1.0 Preview 5 on Win 11 21H2 22000.469. I still have the same issue, Xamarin debugging working fine, Maui debugging I have the same issue.

Comment: Any suggestions of what to try next i.e. what/where/how I could provide logging?  Not being able to debug on iOS is a real problem